# SQL Server Query for a DVD Rental Company

Tags: sql

I've got a sample database for a movie rental business. I'm trying to write a query that finds all movie titles that are currently sold out.

- All DVDs for that film are currently rented. Or...
- No DVDs exist for that film

Keep in mind I want to make sure this query doesn't capture DVDs that are in inventory but have never appeared in the rental table.

Edit: this is what I have so far, but I can't account for the scenario in the line above^.

```
SELECT Count(DvdID) AS Inventory, Movie.Title
FROM Dvd
JOIN Movie on Dvd.MovieID = Movie.MovieID
WHERE Dvd.DvdID IN
    (SELECT RentalID
    FROM Rental
    WHERE Rental.ReturnDate IS NULL)
OR Dvd.DvdID NOT IN
    (SELECT Dvd.DvdID
    FROM Dvd
    WHERE DvdID NOT IN
    (SELECT Rental.DvdID FROM RENTAL)
    )

GROUP BY Movie.Title
```

TABLES:

### Movie

-MovieID

-MovieTitle

### Dvd

-DvdID

-MovieID

### Rental

-RentalID

-DvdID

-AccountID

-RentalDate

-ReturnDate

Comment: *‘I want to make sure this query doesn't capture DVDs that are in inventory but have never appeared in the rental table.’* – do you mean you want the query to ignore such DVDs as if they don't exist? More specifically, I'm trying to understand what the `Inventory` column should display. For instance, there are two DVDs with a movie "ABC". One of the DVDs has never been rented yet (is absent from `Rental`), the other is rented at the moment. What value should the Inventory column show for "ABC", 1 or 2?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to correct mistake in first subquery - should be `DvdID` not `RentalID`. This query work for me, works for you?

Query:

```
SELECT Count(DvdID) AS Inventory, MovieTitle
FROM Dvd
JOIN Movie on Dvd.MovieID = Movie.MovieID
WHERE Dvd.DvdID IN
    (SELECT DvdID
    FROM Rental
    WHERE Rental.ReturnDate IS NULL)
OR Dvd.DvdID NOT IN
    (SELECT Dvd.DvdID
    FROM Dvd
    WHERE DvdID NOT IN
    (SELECT Rental.DvdID FROM RENTAL)
    )
GROUP BY MovieTitle
```